# PHP Sort array before other operations

Tags: php, sorting

Doing for each loop but data is out of order
I have tried several variations but cannot get to sort on sub array

---

Running this for each loop

```
@foreach($record->criteria_list as $optKey=>$options)
```

I need to sort based on the below field and make main array ($record)sorted before the for loop

```
$options->total_passed_user
```

The other 9 examples(that i have tried) and 2 of the below are part of those examples are erroring out...page wont load....
Yes it is blade/laravel but that doesnt matter as im trying to sort this array prior to the loop and the php formatting.page loads and all code works , just order of items is out of place and trying to reorder based on $options->total_passed_user

```
@foreach($record->criteria_list as $optKey=>$options)

<?php
    $correctPercentage = ( $record->total_test_completed_count) ? round(($options->total_passed_user/$record->total_test_completed_count)*100):0;
```

etc.......

Comment: Welcome ! That's unclear. Can you share a sample of your data and the expected result ?

Comment: Why `@foreach` and not simply `foreach`

Comment: @RiggsFolly maybe it's blade?

Comment: @u_mulder Ahh maybe

Answer (score 0):

I think, `usort` function will works. http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

---

**Example 1 (in PHP ≥7.0): Recomended Solution**

```
usort($record->criteria_list, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a->total_passed_user <=> $b->total_passed_user;
});

...

@foreach($record->criteria_list as $optKey=>$options)
```

---

**Example 2:**

```
function cmp_by_total_passed_user($a, $b) {
  return $a->total_passed_user - $b->total_passed_user;
}

...

usort($record->criteria_list, "cmp_by_total_passed_user");

....

@foreach($record->criteria_list as $optKey=>$options)
```